# SharePoint 2019 list If I select yes option I have a multichoice dropdown that has the response of Yes or No

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list

SharePoint 2019 list: If I select the yes option, I have a multichoice dropdown with the response of Yes or No. If the response is set to yes, then I need it to make other column should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with SharePoint Designer. First go to your list and click. You can edit the NewForm.aspx or you can create a new form.

Then, right click and "Edit file in advanced mode".
Add ID to your `tr` row which you want to hide and show.

[image]

After `</tr>` tag; you can insert JQuery functions.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
   $(function(){ 
    var thechkBox=document.getElementById(&quot;IDOFCHECKBOX&quot;);
    thechkBox.addEventListener(&quot;click&quot;, ifclicked);                       
    
      });
      
      function ifclicked(){
      if( $(&apos;IDOFCHECKBOX&apos;).is(&apos;:checked&apos;) ){
        
        document.getElementById(&quot;choiceTestListTr&quot;).style.display=&quot;table-row&quot;;                      
   
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(&quot;choiceTestListTr&quot;).style.display=&quot;none&quot;;
    }
      }
</script>
```